# Magento 2.2.4 : post data in url

Tags: magento2, controllers, forms, post-data, request

I want to get parameters from my page to the second. My values are submitted in the first page, but I can't achieve to get data on my second page (where I want to display theses data). I'm trying this from one controller to another.

Here's history.php (first controller)

```
public function execute()
    {

        if ('POST' == $this->getRequest()->getMethod()) {

            $detailCommande = $this->getRequest()->getPost('detailCommande');
//            var_dump($detailCommande);

            if ($detailCommande != '') {
                $this->_redirect('recapitulatif/order/recapitulatif', array('_secured' => true, 'detailCommande' => $detailCommande));
            }

        }

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('My Orders'));

        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('customer.account.link.back');
        if ($block) {
            $block->setRefererUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        }
        return $resultPage;
    }
```

The second controller (where I want to display)

```
public function execute() {

$post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

echo "<pre>";
print_r($post);
exit;

$this->_view->loadLayout();
$this->_view->renderLayout();
}
```

I have 2 more questions, is that possible pass an array as data in magento (data = my $_POST values) ? and is it possible to hide parameters in the url during a post request ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant create a POST request from a redirect, [the thing you can do is repeat the request to another url](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect)

You can try passing data with query string

Answer (score 0):

**Controller - 1 (firstController)**

```
$data = $this->_request->getPost();
$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
$param_data = json_encode($data);
$resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/secondController', ['mydata' => $param_data]);
return $resultRedirect;
```

**Controller - 2 (secondController)**

```
$data = $this->_request->getParams();
$my_data = json_decode($data['mydata'], true);
print_r($my_data);
```